# How to create new portal user using web/signup url in odoo

Tags: odoo

Hello I want to create new portal users using web/signup url using backend. I want to create like this because I want to add tests in my module. My module assigns company id of users that created by using /web/signup page. I have multiple website. If user signup from website 1, it will assign company of website 1 in created users.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new user record by using `create` method from `res.user` model. For example,

```
self.env['res.user'].create({...})
```

You will need to pass an object containing required fields into the method for it to work though.

Comment: I know this way. But I want to create user calling this method https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11f44de490d7e9c59b76aaade1d31b3041c9fb3b/addons/auth_signup/models/res_users.py#L56. This method is called by endpoint /web/signup.

Comment: @Neural Try `self.env['res.user'].signup({'login':'your_login','password':'your_password'})`